# Erlang won't let me end a function

Tags: syntax, erlang

here's my code for an RPS game. I keep getting a syntax error whenever I try to put "end." and it won't let me end the function. It says syntax error before: 'end'.

```
-module(project).
-export([rps/0]).

rps() ->
    Computer = rand:uniform(3),
    {ok,Player} = io:read("Rock, Paper, or Scissors?"),
    Win = fun() -> io:fwrite("You Win!"),
    Lose = fun() -> io:fwrite("You Lose."),

    % player chooses rock (win, lose)
    if
        Player == "Rock" ->
            if
                Computer == 3 ->
                    Win();
                Computer == 2 ->
                    Lose()
            end;
    % player chooses paper (win, lose)
    if
        Player == "Paper" ->
            if
                Computer == 1 ->
                    Win();
                Computer == 3 ->
                    Lose()
            end;
    % player chooses scissors (win, lose)
    if
        Player == "Scissors" ->
            if
                Computer == 2 ->
                    Win();
                Computer == 1 ->
                    Lose()
            end;
end.  <--------- (this is where error occurs)
```

Comment: I don't do Erlang, but it looks to me like you have a bunch of unterminated `if` statements (that is, several missing `end`s). https://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html#if

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were a few mistakes here:

- fun without "end" (x2) Win = fun() -> io:fwrite("You Win!") end,
- if-syntax

correct code:

```
-module(project).
-export([rps/0]).

rps() ->
    Computer = rand:uniform(3),
    {ok,Player} = io:read("Rock, Paper, or Scissors?"),
    Win = fun() -> io:fwrite("You Win!") end,
    Lose = fun() -> io:fwrite("You Lose.") end,

    % player chooses rock (win, lose)
    if
        Player == "Rock" ->
            if
                Computer == 3 ->
                    Win();
                Computer == 2 ->
                    Lose()
            end;
    % player chooses paper (win, lose)
        Player == "Paper" ->
            if
                Computer == 1 ->
                    Win();
                Computer == 3 ->
                    Lose()
            end;
    % player chooses scissors (win, lose)
        Player == "Scissors" ->
            if
                Computer == 2 ->
                    Win();
                Computer == 1 ->
                    Lose()
            end
    end.
```

Answer (score 3):

[Artee's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74107020/113848) explained where and how the syntax error occurs. Let me suggest a different way to write this, which can be considered a bit more "Erlang-like", and incidentally gets rid of the syntax errors.

First, let's make the `Computer` variable contain the computer's choice in the same format as the player's:

```
Computer = element(rand:uniform(3), {"Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"}),
```

Then, create a function that takes the player's choice and the computer's choice, and returns who wins:

```
who_wins("Rock", "Scissors") ->
    player;
who_wins("Rock", "Paper") ->
    computer;
who_wins("Paper", "Scissors") ->
    computer;
who_wins("Paper", "Rock") ->
    player;
who_wins("Scissors", "Rock") ->
    computer;
who_wins("Scissors", "Paper") ->
    player;
who_wins(Same, Same) ->
    tie.
```

(In the last clause, since we use the same variable name for both arguments, this clause will match only if the arguments are identical.)

Then, back in the `rps` function, we can replace the nested `if` expressions with:

```
case who_wins(Player, Computer) of
    player ->
        Win();
    computer ->
        Lose();
    tie ->
        io:fwrite("It's a tie!")
end.
```